# react big calendar connect with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, calendar

my events are not displaying the calendar. I use  react for the frontend and for the database I use firebase`your text`

event detais hold display in the calender

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import format from "date-fns/format";
import getDay from "date-fns/getDay";
import parse from "date-fns/parse";
import startOfWeek from "date-fns/startOfWeek";
import  { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Calendar, dateFnsLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import {db} from '../../firebase-config'
import {collection,getDocs} from "firebase/firestore"





const locales = {
    "en-US": require("date-fns/locale/en-US"),
  };
  const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
    format,
    parse,
    startOfWeek,
    getDay,
    locales,
  });

const Sug_view_timetable = () => {

    const BusRouteCollectionRef =collection(db, "bus_routes");
    const [bus_routes,setbus_routes] =useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const getBusRoutes =async()=>{
         const data =await getDocs(BusRouteCollectionRef);
         setbus_routes(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id :doc.id})))
        }
        getBusRoutes ();
        
     
       },[])

     
      
  
  
  return (
    <div>
    
    <Calendar localizer={localizer} events={bus_routes} startAccessor="start"endAccessor="end"  style={{ height: 500, margin: "50px" }} />  
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sug_view_timetable;
```

Comment: this was my code but it didn't work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).